# AWS EC2 Angular App Deployed and use DNS from Godaddy, failing in Configuration

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using `AWS EC2` instance for Angular APP Deployment, I have assigned `Elastic IP` Address as well.

I am applying below command to run angular app on `EC2` from `putty session`.

```
nohup ng serve --port 4202 --host 0.0.0.0 --public-host ec2-X-XXX-XXX-XXX.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com > nglog.out &
```

I am able to access over Elastic IP and port over public internet.

```
http://X.XXX.XXX.XXX:4202/
```

This is accessible but not via public host provided by AWS.

Now I wanted to add `A` record entry in Godaddy, I am facing issue because I cant add `port number` here i.e. `4202` only IP Address I am able to configure.
I need to know how to add port.

Or Do I have to use `NGINX` in my EC2 server and start using NGINX server ? or still option available in `GODADDY` to add `IP:PORT`.

Other problem is I am not able to access after I close my `Putty session`, the server stops.

Comment: DNS doesnt care about ports - its just for mapping hostnames to IP's.  If you want to change the port you would need to reverse proxy it (via nginx or with AWS load balancer etc). Also, you need to run your app as a service, not from an interactive shell or it will exit when you log out.

Comment: Hi @MisterSmith can you please help me into this, in setting up, I thought that at sometime I have to introduce `nginx`, can you guide me in terms of `Run As A Service`. or which would be better, `Run As A Service` or adding `ALB`

Comment: I'm sorry - what you are asking is outside the scope of stackoverflow - npm/nginx/ec2 are complex topics in their own right and your question isnt really programming related. I suggest you find and follow a few tutorials online to understand the basics before you try and tackle your application.